# Class design 'dilemma'

Tags: class-design

I never did proper class design, so bear with me.

Let's say we have a `Project` class. Then let's say we have a `ProjectGroup` class that has the same members as the `Project` class, plus a list of `Project`s.

Should `ProjectGroup` be the superclass of `Project` or is `ProjectGroup` a specialization of `Project` and the former should be a subclass of the latter?

Comment: not an answer to your immeduate problem but check out Domain Driven DEsign by Eric Evans, or Object Thinking by David West.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat I'll have a look, tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I won't bother you with theory**, because you're probably in a hurry to get a quick answer. So here it goes:

If your two classes are actually implying they should be related by inheritance then `ProjectGroup` should inherit from `Project` class. This is how it would look like in C#:

```
public class ProjectGroup: Project ...
```

If they are not, but they use some common class members (that define their state and some functionality over that state), then I'd write an interface and implement it in both classes. C# code again:

```
public interface ICommonState ...

public class Project: ICommonState ...

public class ProjectGroup: ICommonState
{
    IEnumerable<ICommonState> projects
    ...
}
```

### Edit

If your classes are actually `Project` and `ProjectGroup` and they both have properties like `ID` and `Name` in common (for instance), they still shouldn't be inherited. They just happen to have properties with the same name, but they are basically different entities.

They could both either

- implement an `ICommonEntity` interface - use it when they have the same state+functionality but functionality behaves differently in each of them
- inherit from `CommonEntity` class - use it when functionality is completely identical; this way you'll follow the *DRY* (don't repeat yourself) philosophy

So your component may be an interface or a class (when using composite pattern).

Direct inheritance between two classes is more suitable where entities imply on being in relation to each other. Like `User` and `Person` classes. They can be inherited either way. Depending on the business scenario.

```
class User: Person
```

This would be the case where you have an application with contacts. Some of them are also users of this very same application.

```
class Person: User
```

This would be a web site where you can register as a user. In case you fill up some personal details as well your user data becomes of type `Person`.

Comment: If you are willing to elaborate, please do. This is related to a minor part of the project I'm writing, so I'm in no hurry.

Comment: Since the two classes methods perform the exact same operation (the difference is only the addition of the `Project`s list and method to handle them, does it make sense that the Component (as used in Composite Pattern) is a class instead of an interface?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might want the Composite pattern.  Both LeafProject and CompositeProject implement the Project interface, and CompositeProject also holds a collection of Project instances.

Comment: This is interesting, I'll look for more info about this Composite Pattern

Comment: @klez: My interface implementation is basically composite pattern.

Answer (score 0):

if the member list of projects is unique to projectgroup and does not apply to all types of projects, then make project your super/base class and derive projectgroup from project.